# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 how to add an Image to a Label

Tags: image, javafx, label, scenebuilder

I am using `JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0` and I would like to add an `image` to a `label` using FXML.

In [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/label.htm), we can find how to achieve this using Java code, but I would like to achieve this using Scene Builder

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to achieve this

- Using FXML
- Using CSS

**FXML**

```
<Label text="My Image">
   <graphic>
      <ImageView fitWidth="150" preserveRatio="true" smooth="true">
        <image>
          <Image url="myImage.png"/>
        </image>
      </ImageView>
   </graphic>
</Label>
```

Inside Scene Builder, drag an ImageView on top of a Label and it will automatically be set as a graphic for the label. Then select the ImageView and type the url of the image into the ImageView's image field in the Scene Builder properties pane.

**CSS**

Assign an `id` to the `Label` in your FXML. You will also find an `id` as the property of the Label in Scene Builder

```
<Label text= "My Image" id = "labelwithimage"/>
```

Now you can either assign the css values directly in fxml(makes things clumsy) or create a new css file and define your attributes in it

*Direct Assignment*

```
<Label text= "My Image" id = "labelwithimage" style="-fx-graphic:url('myImage.png'); -fx-graphic-text-gap : 10;"/>
```

For defining it in a css file, you need to create a css file, define the atrributes against the `id` assigned to the `Label` and include it in the FXML

*mycss.css*

```
#labelwithimage {          
    -fx-graphic: url("myImage.png");
    -fx-graphic-text-gap : 10;
}
```

As you might have already guessed, `-fx-graphic` does everything that we wrote inside `<graphic></graphic>`, there are few other attributes like `-fx-graphic-text-gap`. You can find all the tags that can be used on `Label` in the [css reference guide for label](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label)

Now the last thing in css is loading the css in the fxml. For this you need to include the following tag inside you fxml

```
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@mycss.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

*Just make sure to have the proper imports in the FXML*

Comment: and there is one more way, in java code with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to do it directly in the Scene Builder, without touching the FXML or CSS manually.

Just drag and drop an ImageView node onto your label. You can then set the path to the image on the added ImageView node.

Alternatively, you may just drag an image file from your file explorer (or equivalent) to the label in Scene Builder. Scene Builder will add the intermediate ImageView node automatically. You may then adjust the path to your needs (document-relative, classpath-relative, etc.).

Actually the method is the same as in Java code and the direct modifications of the FXML: just set an ImageView as being the 'graphic' node of the label.

This also works the same for buttons.